# Substituting Carapils with left overs

Tags: substitution

I have a recipe for an English I.P.A. which has 0.500 gr of Carapils but i have run out.Only grains that i have right now for substitute is Cara-Blonde and Crystal EBC 145-155. Will either of those two do or just skip Carapils and start the brew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you'll be fine with the cara-blonde - that's only a few shades lighter than carapils.

It really depends upon what other crystal malts are in the brew. If there are other crystals around the 20-40L, then you may not need so much of the carablonde. Then you could use 250g of that, and 250g of base malt, to avoid it becoming too sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reminder, the cara/crystal malts don't add any fermentable sugars, they are only for color, body and sweetness depending on the level of carmelizaton. Substituting any light cara malt should be fine.

Comment: Actually, they do add fermentable sugars, although not as fermentable as a base malt.